# weird output for Printf unsigned long size_t

Tags: c, printf

I encountered this issue while testing around printf.

This code outputs **5**, which is what I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t  ft_strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t  i;

    while (*str++)
        i++;
    return (i);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%zu\n", ft_strlen("Hello"));
    return (0);
}
```

But, when I declare a `char *str;` above my printf, the output shows ***4294967301***

Why is the printf affected by the above declaration ?

Comment: Function `ft_strlen()` fails to initialize its local variable `i`.

Comment: Added `i = 0` and solved it..   Thanks.

Comment: Note, while the counter approach to `strlen()` works fine for short strings, it become much less efficient than the library implementation for longer strings. (the library version typically checks 4-bytes at a time for `\0`)

Comment: Thanks for the info @DavidC.Rankin, but I have to use my own ft_strlen() for my school assignment.  I'll sure take a look at strlen() later!

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with that. Just making you aware when you work with long strings (1000+ characters) you will see a sizeable difference in efficiency, and by the time you get to 1000000 character strings you will see orders of magnitude difference in execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Initialising `int i to 0` resolved my issue.

```
size_t  ft_strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    while (*str++)
        i++;
    return (i);
}
```

Comment: You do know you can do `size_t i = 0;`, right?  It's just that little bit neater.

Comment: Yes I do, but I have to follow my school norm, which i can't declare and initialize my variable on the same line.

Comment: Ok, c'est la vie.  Beats me what they teach in school these days.